# Code to Send image+message to telegram bot using raspberry pi

Tags: python

How to write a code such that when we press the button in web cam it automatically send image into telegram bot..

Answer (score -1):

You can write code in raspberry pi as you would do in any Linux machine. Connect a monitor, keyboard and mouse to your pi and start writing code. 
If you don't have a keyboard or monitor with you, you can also SSH into pi.